# Is the paging file part of the heap? And am I correct in thinking that the heap doesn't have to be a continuous block of memory?

Tags: file, assembly, heap-memory, paging

Just two simple questions I could not find a proper answer to. I decided I would learn assembly language since its one area of my programming capabilities that lacks.

Also where functions are called recursively, how does the OS determine how large the stack should be for a thread? or does it just place the stack where there is a large amount of memory it can expand into before colliding with the heap?

Comment: The paging file is part of the way virtual memory is managed. The heap can be fragmented by usage, so it *might* not necessary for it to be contiguous. The OS does not know how deep your recursive function will go. The stack is allocated a default amount of memory. There are ways to override that. But on a PC I never do so I don't know how. Finally basic assembly language does not have a heap, which is a property of higher level languages.

Comment: none of this has anything to do with learning assembly language.

Comment: stack tends to start at the top and crash into the heap.  from a programs perspective one would assume heap is linear and stack as well.  but there are always exceptions.   from the programs perspectve means on the virtual side of the mmu.  on the physical side there is no reason for it to be linear, up to the operating system.

Comment: heap is defined by the operating system or other software that manages it.  so one operating system or operating environment may have a different definition than another.  the compiler might be involved as well.  this question does not have simple single answers, it is an "it depends" thing

Answer (score 0):

> Is the paging file part of the heap?

Not really.  You can't access it directly; the OS may use it transparently to page out parts of your process's virtual address space.

> the heap doesn't have to be a continuous block of memory?

Yes, allocations with `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` are considered part of the heap, and can be anywhere in your virtual address space.  As Weather Vane points out, "heap" is a pretty broad / archaic term.  It's not a useful concept for understanding what *really* happens under the hood.

e.g. you can `mmap` a file to make its contents part of your virtual address space.  Is that part of the "heap"?  I don't know and don't care.

> Also where functions are called recursively, how does the OS determine how large the stack should be for a thread?

It just sets a max stack size limit when your process starts.  Using recursive functions has nothing to do with it.  (Although it's the most common way to use up the fixed size limit, the other being large local arrays).